# Is it possible to use Mono static compilation on Windows?

Tags: static, mono, compilation

I was wondering if it is possible to use Mono static compilation on Windows. If so,  what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean with static compilation? You want to compile so .NET is not needed?

Comment: I think he meant using Mono without the requirement of JIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

http://www.mono-project.com/AOT#Supported_Platforms

Answer (score 9):

To statically compile your code, you use the tool `mkbundle'.

The mkbundle tool requires a cygwin setup (it needs the assembler, linker and compiler) to generate the static binary.

Comment: AND THIS WILL WORK WITHOUT .NET RUNTIME?? ***shock*** :O